# Citadel mail server (citserver) not registering network ports

Tags: server, email

I was running Citadel on Ubuntu 18.04 with citadel-server and citadel-webcit packages installed. After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 the citadel service starts but does not register any ports. netstat shows no listener on the relevant ports for IMAP, SNMP, POP and the internal communication. Webcit does register but is not able to communicate to citserver.
service citadel status shows the service is running, ps shows the processes being there and active.
Tried to remove and re-install using apt as well as dpkg-reconfigure but nothing seems to change the behavior.

Comment: Is it possible that Citadel  needs to be updated to work with Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this issue is caused by the citadel version provided through apt  in the repo (917-4). Seems this build has an issue as I could also not get it to work on an fresh install of 20.04. The solution in the end was to install from source using citadel Easy Install. It will build the software and works fine. A bit of manual work is required then to amend all the scripts and installation paths.